# Recreate all binding on element (or custom binding markup extensions?)

Tags: .net, wpf

The problem I am facing lies in the fact a binding utilizing `RelativeSource` does not update its target when element the binding's applied to changes its position in the visual tree.

So, if one has the following fragment of code:

```
<Border Tag="Border1">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" />
</Border>

<Border Tag="Border2" />
```

Then an attempt to remove the `TextBlock` from the first `Border` and adding it to the second will not result in the `TextBlock` changing its `Text` value.

The easiest workaround I can think of is to recreate all bindings that use RelativeSource and are applied to the element's subtree (simply calling to `UpdateTarget` does no good). Does anybody know how one can do so?
Calling to `ClearBinding`-`SetBinding` is easy enough, but how to find all dependency properties that need to be recreated? I can't find a way to reliably collect all dependency properties of an object (including attached).

Another theoretically possible approach is to subclass `BindingBase` and so it will track `Visual` elements in the path to the actual source. Though I am quite sure there be some internal sealed stuff preventing from accomplishing this.

Any thoughts and alternative solutions are welcome.

Comment: I'm curious as to why are you moving elements in the Visual Tree like that to begin with.

Comment: Err, I'm building PropertyGrid control where an editor for a property is only created once, but the container it resides in can be recreated by the parent `ItemsControl` (in the case when a user reselects an object). Currently an editor is a `Control` (as opposed to viewmodel + corresponding `DataTemplate`). Perharps, I could change that, but it isn't going to be an easy change at this point. :(

Comment: It would seem to me that the use of the `Tag` property for whatever purpose in WPF is nothing but a HACK. There are certainly several much better mechanisms so associate a certain UI element with any given piece of data (Attached Properties, DataBinding and whatnot) than using the `Tag` property.

Comment: It was just an example...

Comment: Then yes, if you stop and think for a second, persisting the items' data in a ViewModel or Model becomes a **need** when using a `Virtualizing` ItemsControl. since the UI is dynamically being destroyed / recreated / recycled to different data items, you cannot trust it to keep the state of data. Therefore you need a VM.

Comment: Yes and no. I do have a model for each property where I store data. I do not however store there data that is of no interest to business. For example, I will store there Value of a property, but will not store flag indicating whether or not the property is expanded (since it's perfectly fine for a UI for that property to be in collapsed state if a user reselected the object).

Comment: Instead, keyboard navigation, selection, ability to expand are implemented as attached behaviors (via attached properties). And the problem is that those behaviors rely on bindings with RelativeSource set. (Probably an easy to understand example would be this: indent of property panel = indent of parent property panel + x)

Comment: It's an interesting scenario. I wonder if it would be convenient for you to subclass `ItemsControl` and do something about the `GetContainerForItem()` stuff

Comment: Why do not just simply try to use attachable dependency properties & ICommand interface wile using correct MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the `DataContext` of your Borders and in the `TextBox` use a binding to inherited `DataContext` it should work:

```
   <Border x:Name="b1" 
           Tag="Border1"
           DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag}" />
    </Border>

    <Border x:Name="b2" 
            Tag="Border2" 
            DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```